# How to reconnect to Database quick in AsyncTask?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-asynctask

If the database connection gets lost, it took more than one minute to reconnect. How can I speed up that reconnect?

```
class MssqlConnectorHelper (val view: View){

private var isConnected = false
lateinit var  mssqlConnector :MssqlConnector
var quitTask = false

inner class SyncData : AsyncTask<String, String, String>() {

    override fun onPreExecute() {
        mssqlConnector = MssqlConnector()
    }

    override fun doInBackground(vararg params: String?): String {
        var conn : Connection? = null

        while (!quitTask) {
            if (conn == null || !isConnected) {
                conn = mssqlConnector?.dbConn()
                isConnected = conn != null
            }

            if (conn != null && isConnected) {
                try {
                    val preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(params[0])
                    val cursor = preparedStatement.executeQuery()
                    if (cursor != null) {
                        while (cursor.next()) {
                            Log.i("SQL Result: ", cursor.getInt(1).toString() + " "
                                    + cursor.getInt(2).toString() + " "
                                    + cursor.getInt(3).toString() + " "
                                    + cursor.getInt(4).toString())
                        }
                    }
                }catch (e : Exception) {
                    isConnected = false
                    conn = null
                    Log.e("SQL Error", "Database Exception: "+e.message)
                }
            }else {
                Log.e("SQL Error", "Connection Error")
            }
            Thread.sleep(3000)
        }
        return "end background"
    }
}

fun getPickUpOrder() {
    SyncData().execute("SELECT * FROM pickUpOrder WHERE iStatus = 4")
}
}
```

I get an Network error IOException: Connection refused and a ConnectException: Connection refused. After that the reconnect works fine.

Comment: Have you considered exposing the data from the database through a REST API / backend rather than the entire database exposed directly to the outside world?

Comment: its only a private app and the database does not provide any APIs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by myself and it's quite easy, just adding the timeout to the jtds URL:

```
"jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://$ip:$port;instance=MSSQLSERVER;databaseName=$db;user=$username;password=$password;loginTimeout=5"
```